# SQL Query problems exist

Tags: sql, exists

I'm having a lot of troubles with the last query I need and I think it's a level out of my league so any help is appreciated.

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Recipe
(
     nrecipe     integer, 
     name         varchar(255),
     primary key (nrecipe)
);

CREATE TABLE Food
(
    designation  varchar(255)   unique,
    quantity     integer,
    primary key (designation)
);

CREATE TABLE Contains
(
     nrecipe      integer,
     designation  varchar(255),
     quantity     integer,
     primary key (nrecipe, designation),
     foreign key (nrecipe) references Recepie (nrecipe),
     foreign key (designation) references Food (designation)
);
```

`Quantity` in `Food` table is the quantity stored in warehouse.

`Quantity` in `Contains` is the amount needed of a food element to use in recipe.

`Quantity` in `Food` table and `Contains` differ from each other.

The query:

I want to know the names of ALL recipes that are possible to be done with the food stored in warehouse.

It requires that the quantity of every element of food in warehouse is bigger than the quantity needed for the recipe.

EDIT: also, it shouldn't show a recipe's name if there is nothing referring to it on `Contains` table.

To make it easier to understand, I'll give some data:

```
INSERT INTO Recipe  VALUES ('01', 'Steak with potatos and water');
INSERT INTO Recipe  VALUES ('02', 'Rice and ice tea');
INSERT INTO Recipe  VALUES ('03', 'Potatos and shrimp');
INSERT INTO Recipe  VALUES ('04', 'Water');
INSERT INTO Recipe  VALUES ('05', 'Steak with rice');
INSERT INTO Recipe  VALUES ('06', 'Steak with spaguetti');
INSERT INTO Recipe  VALUES ('07', 'Potatos with rice');

INSERT INTO Food    VALUES ('Water', 5);
INSERT INTO Food    VALUES ('Ice tea', 10);
INSERT INTO Food    VALUES ('Steak', 30);
INSERT INTO Food    VALUES ('Potatos', 20);
INSERT INTO Food    VALUES ('Rice', 50);
INSERT INTO Food    VALUES ('Shrimp', 5);
INSERT INTO Food    VALUES ('Spaguetti', 5);

INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('01', 'Steak', 1);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('01', 'Potatos', 15);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('01', 'Water', 10);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('02', 'Rice', 5);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('02', 'Ice tea', 8);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('03', 'Potatos', 1);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('03', 'Shrimp', 10);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('04', 'Water', 20);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('05', 'Steak', 1);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('05', 'Rice', 20);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('06', 'Steak', 1);
INSERT INTO Contains    VALUES ('06', 'Spaguetti', 10);
```

The outcome expected from the query is:

```
Rice and ice tea
Steak with rice
```

Since it's the only two recipes with enough quantity in warehouse.

EDIT: potatoes with rice shouldn't appear as it is a recipe but isn't in contains list

Thanks for input and time. Any help is welcome :)

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Also what database is this for as the way to do it may differ slightly based on the environment.

Comment: @ Mitch 

I was toggling with Exists clause but get lost in the nested clauses :/

@Payload

It's for a friend that asked me to do it and it's just for her to keep track of the recipes she can do with the content of her kitchen. She has some abusive storage room lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `>= ALL` operator :

```
SELECT name
  FROM Recipe R
 WHERE 0 >= ALL (SELECT C.quantity - F.quantity
                   FROM Food F
             INNER JOIN Contains C
                  USING (designation)
                  WHERE C.nrecipe = R.nrecipe);
```

The correct spelling is recipe, and you used different names for some columns (recepie, nrecipe, nrecepie) so I changed it. Note that instead of using a varchar primary key, you should use a numeric one.

**Edit:**

```
SELECT name
  FROM Recipe R
 WHERE 0 >= ALL (SELECT C.quantity - F.quantity
                   FROM Food F
             INNER JOIN Contains C
                  USING (designation)
                  WHERE C.nrecipe = R.nrecipe)
   AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM Contains C
               WHERE C.nrecipe = R.nrecipe);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I didn't copy paste it I had to traslate it all and just typed so there are some bugs.   This seems to work fine but there is one more problem. It gave me a result that wasn't present and I forgot to point it out. It shouldn't give a name of recipe if there aren't any food elements. As a test, I'll add to the front page, put INSERT INTO Recipe VALUES ('07', 'Potatos with rice'); and it will appear as a result and I didn't wanted that.

Comment: @Martin : I edited. I couldn't find a more elegant way to do this, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

This is in SQL Server because that is what I have:

```
select
    r.name
from
    Recepie r
where
    not exists 
    (
        select 1
        from
            [Contains] c
        where
            c.nrecipe = r.nrecepie and
            not exists 
            (
                select 1
                from
                    Food f
                where
                    f.designation = c.designation and
                    f.quantity >= c.quantity
            )
    )
```

Which in plain language is "Get me all recipes where there are no ingredients of insufficient quantity"

Comment: It works as well as the other given answer but has the same problem that I forgot to point out. If there is a recipe but it isn't present in Contains table it shouldn't be shown